# How to preserve comments with YUI compressor

Tags: yui-compressor

I'm using the YUI compressor to merge and minify my JS-files.
One problem I'm having is that comments are being deleted, even though I'm using the suggested format as follows:

```
/*!

comments go here

*/
```

That's what they say in the documentation and on several blogs:

http://www.julienlecomte.net/yuicompressor/README

http://www.electrictoolbox.com/preserve-comments-yui-compressor/

Any ideas on what can be wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I re-ran YUI compressor and now all comments are in place. Probably my own fault...